# How should I type a mock object

Tags: typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

How should I type a mock object of a service ?

Suppose I have `MyService` that has `someMethod`.
I create a mock of `MyService` like this:

```
let mockMyService = jasmine.createSpyObject('mockMyService', ['someMethod'])
```

How should I type `mockMyService` ?

If I type it as `MyService`, the typescript compliler won't let met do `mockMyService.someMethod.and`

Answer (score 1):

I've just been wondering this myself and while this may not be the correct method, I have gone with the below approach when defining the type of a mock/spy of a service.

```
const mockMyService: jasmine.SpyObj<MyService> = jasmine.createSpyObject('mockMyService', ['someMethod']);
```

I've then been able to go on and reset the calls of this spy, when required, without any complaints from the compiler or Sublime.

```
mockMyService.someMethod.calls.reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, according to the [documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/jasmine.html), isn't it called `createSpyObj` instead of `createSpyObject`?

However it states that it returns an object as Spys as its members:

> *(static) createSpyObj(baseNameopt, methodNames) → {Object}*
>
> Create an object with multiple Spys as its members.

So it's not directly a `jasmine.Spy` object, but an object of type `{ [key: string]: jasmine.Spy }`.

```
let mockMyService: { [key: string]: jasmine.Spy } = jasmine.createSpyObj('mockMyService', ['someMethod']);
```

However, if you only spy on one method you could just simply do:

```
let mockMyService: jasmine.Spy = createSpy('mockMyService', 'someMethod');
```

Hope i could help.

Answer (score -1):

You can type the mock in the usual way:

```ts
let mockMyService: MyService = jasmine.createSpyObj('mockMyService', ['someMethod']);
```

The problem you're seeing when you try to use its methods as spies is that *you haven't told TypeScript they're spies*, try:

```ts
(mockMyService.someMethod as Spy).and.returnValue(...);
                       // ^ note
```